# NavigationView menu item not selecting on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, drawerlayout, android-navigationview

I've created a NavigationView using android support library v-7:27.1.1

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" 
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/tab_color"/>
```

There is a problem with menu items
@menu/nav_menu.xml

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_circle"
            android:title="Item 1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_cellphone_android"
            android:title="Item 2"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_circle"
            android:title="Item 3"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_cellphone_android"
            android:title="Item 4"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item5"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_circle"
            android:title="Item 5"/>
        
    </group>
    
</menu>
```

@color/tab_color

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FD12F5" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="#aaaaaa" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

here's the output on a real device
[image]

When I clicked on item nothing happens
no highlights item and no selected

What is problem?

Note: I am using AIDE application

Comment: Post the layout with the drawerLayout and the NavigationView

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you need to change `android:state_selected` into `android:state_checked`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#FD12F5" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="#aaaaaa" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Side note: [support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) are deprecated / End of support now, and replaced by [androidx libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

Answer (score 0):

i migrated support library to androidx
and my problem is solved
thank @Zain